# Rails: How to determine controller/action in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my form partial:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :photo_attributes, :html => { :multipart => true } do |d| %>
    <%= d.label :image, :label => 'Upload logo', :required => false  %>
    <%= d.file_field :image, :label => 'Image, :required => false', :style => 'margin-bottom:2px'  %>
    <%= d.input :image_url, :label => 'Billed URL', :required => false %>
<% end %>
```

If the action is edit I want to show this instead:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :photo, :html => { :multipart => true } do |d| %>
    <%= d.label :image, :label => 'Upload logo', :required => false  %>
    <%= d.file_field :image, :label => 'Image, :required => false', :style => 'margin-bottom:2px'  %>
    <%= d.input :image_url, :label => 'Billed URL', :required => false %>
<% end %>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Generally the form partial only contains the fields, not the form tag or the fields for, but if you have no other way, you can always see what `params[:action]` is currently set to and behave accordingly.

Answer (score 117):

`current_page?(action: 'edit')`

See [ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#current_page?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F)

Rails also makes the methods `controller_path`, `controller_name`, `action_name` available for use in the view.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer--`current_page?` is awesome.

Comment: Hmm. I've seen cases where it doesn't work as expected. i.e. when `controller_name == 'site'` and `action_name == 'home'` but `current_page?(controller: 'site', action: 'home')` returns false.

Comment: Agree. This answer is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Heads up! current_page method doesn't work with post request. For example, imagine Facebook's /login page. When you are in login page, on the header you see sign up button and when you are in sign up, it displays login button. If you design such a logic by using current page method, you will end up with two buttons on the page, when you submit login or sign up form and get error. So, page will render again with an error and your method will not work. So, in this case use something like this: if controller_name == 'home' && action_name == 'login'

Answer (score 9):

You could write something like

```
<%- form_url = @object.new_record? ? :photo_attributes : :photo %>
<% f.simple_fields_for form_url, :html => { :multipart => true } do |d| %>
```

That is, if you have an `@object` to check against. Otherwise you could use `action_name` (and even `controller_name`).

So something like:

```
<%- form_url = action_name == :edit ? :photo : :photo_attributes %>
<% f.simple_fields_for form_url, :html => { :multipart => true } do |d| %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

Rails 5: Display Action within the view

```
<%= action_name %>
```

If statement within the view

```
<% if action_name == "edit" %>
  This is an edit action.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use @_controller.action_name in view