# <% if !current_page?(action: 'edit') %> error . No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"…"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

My `_footer.html.erb` is (simplified):

```
<footer class="footer">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse">
      <% if logged_in? %>
         <li class="btn btn-primary"> <%= link_to 'Add New Connection', new_year_path %></li>
         <li class="btn btn-primary"> <%= link_to 'Add New Person', new_person_path %> </li>
         <li class="btn btn-primary"> <%= link_to 'Add New Address/Location', new_location_path %> </li>
      <% end %>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

But I don't want the footer to show up while editing; too easy to click on one of these buttons instead of `Cancel` or `Submit` which is down the page and my footer is stuck to the bottom. `views/layouts/application.html.erb` has `<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>`

I suppose I could have my three `edit.html.erg`s not use the defaults above, but seems easier if I could add another condition on the `_footer.html.erg`. Or some other way. Maybe something about leaving page without submitting?

Based on @tsrandrei comment I tried wrapping the footer in `<% if !current_page?(action: 'edit') %>` blah-blah  `<% end %>` but then get error `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"…"}` with the controller name being whatever the page is relevant to.

Answer (score 3):

```
<% if current_page?(action: 'edit') %>
  <footer class="footer">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse">
      <% if logged_in? %>
         <li class="btn btn-primary"> <%= link_to 'Add New Connection', new_year_path %></li>
         <li class="btn btn-primary"> <%= link_to 'Add New Person', new_person_path %> </li>
         <li class="btn btn-primary"> <%= link_to 'Add New Address/Location', new_location_path %> </li>
      <% end %>
  </nav>
 </footer>
<% end %>
```

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

You will also have other methods for your views:

- controller_path
- controller_name
- action_name

Also check [Rails: How to determine controller/action in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053312/rails-how-to-determine-controller-action-in-view)

Comment: Missing the bang. But close enough. Thank you

Comment: I thought this was working. It does if one stays on the `/edit` page, but on most any other page, the error `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"years"}` or similar. The error has different controllers depending on the page visited.

PS. I did change to `<% if !current_page?(action: 'edit') %>` and thinking this might be part of the error changed back to `<% if current_page?(action: 'edit') %>` with and` if else` but still get errors.